# Postgres : find the minimum of difference between timestamp rows

Tags: postgresql, function, timestamp

I have users, they run and I have a timestamp record of each lap.

I'd like to sort users by fastest lap.

The idea is to use "lag" function of postgres, with a "GROUP BY user_id"

I tried something but I dont know "lag" well, moreover I can't get and window function (lap) work with an aggregation function (min)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ec9dc/6

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks

Comment: I have got to this : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ec9dc/6 but timestamps are mixed between users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to order the users by their lap durations you have to partition the rows by the column `user_id`. Otherwise the lap times of different users will be mixed.

I've taken your example code and modified it a bit: I've removed one time stamp, which was inserted twice and I introduced a view which contains the window functions `rank()` and `lag()`. The former is used to calculate the lap number per user and the latter to determine the preceeding time stamp for the current time stamp.

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TABLE lap
(
  user_id text,
  timestamp timestamp without time zone
);

INSERT INTO lap VALUES
    ('a', '2015-08-20 16:14:30.568'),
    ('a', '2015-08-20 16:16:13.06'),
    ('b', '2015-08-20 16:16:18.06'),
    ('b', '2015-08-20 16:16:25.63'),
    ('b', '2015-08-20 16:17:10.568'),
    ('a', '2015-08-20 16:17:25.63'),
  --('a', '2015-08-20 16:17:34.087'), -- Timestamp was inserted twice.
    ('a', '2015-08-20 16:17:34.087');

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW user_lap_duration AS
    SELECT
        user_id,
        -1+rank() OVER w AS lap_nr,
        lag(timestamp) OVER w AS timestamp_prev,
        timestamp,
        timestamp - lag(timestamp)
            OVER w
          AS lap_duration
    FROM
        lap
        WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY timestamp);

SELECT
    user_id,
    lap_nr,
    lap_duration
FROM
    user_lap_duration
WHERE
    lap_nr <> 0
ORDER BY
    lap_duration;

ROLLBACK;
```

Running above code yields the following output.

```
 user_id | lap_nr | lap_duration 
---------+--------+--------------
 b       |      1 | 00:00:07.57
 a       |      3 | 00:00:08.457
 b       |      2 | 00:00:44.938
 a       |      2 | 00:01:12.57
 a       |      1 | 00:01:42.492
(5 rows)
```